# Localizing text in Javascript onbeforeunload window in CefSharp chromium browser

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I'm trying to change the language in the onbeforeunload window in the CefSharp chromium browser. I'm using the CefSharp.WinForms nuget package v83.4.20.

I don't know much about Javascript or Chromium so if this is something trivial, please excuse my lack of knowledge of these technologies.

I have tried changing the locale settings in the Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings( ... )) section of my code, but this settings doesn't change the language in which the onbeforeunload window appears. I have also added the path to the locales folder containing all the .pak files including the cs (czech) one.

```
var settings = new CefSettings()
{
    BrowserSubprocessPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase,
        Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "x64" : "x86",
        "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe"),
    LogSeverity=LogSeverity.Fatal,
    Locale = "cs"
};

Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

I've read in the documentation that these settings are passed on to the Blink - the rendering engine that Chromium uses, but I have no idea how that could effect localization settings in windows like these.

Do you have any experience with this issue? Or does someone have a working solution where this window appears in a different language than the default English, where I could analyse the differences to my project?
Also I think switching to another version of the nuget package shouldn't be much of an issue.

Comment: What text exactly are you trying to localize?

Comment: There is this window that you can trigger in javascript when user tries to leave the page or close the browser. The window says "Do you want to leave this site? Changes you made may not be saved." Then there are two buttons "Stay" and "Leave". Also a checkbox appears "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs." Way earlier browsers allowed to customize these dialogs which lead to web apps preventing the user from leaving the page. This was at some point changed by all the main webpages including Chrome/chromium so that now you can only trigger this window but you cannot customize it.

Comment: This text and these buttons I would very much like to localize to the language that is the default Windows 10 language of the user running my app.
Here is a link to a Google search on this window/dialog to understand what exactly I mean:
https://www.google.com/search?q=onbeforeunload+javascript+window+unsaved+changes&sxsrf=ALeKk03lSmpKxGnGCCvcGp0wBMb9piLilw:1600415393550&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjT6pn4m_LrAhU-QkEAHWCMCGAQ_AUoAXoECA8QAw&biw=1920&bih=969#imgrc=PJR4LUO8KYkvjM

Comment: Does Chrome display the correctly localized text? Your best bet is likely to display your own custom dialog by implementing http://cefsharp.github.io/api/84.4.x/html/T_CefSharp_IJsDialogHandler.htm

Comment: Yes, Chrome localizes that window. Thank you for your answer. In the mean time our client pulled the plug on this bug, saying at the end of the day there are more pressing issues. But your tip seems like it might just work. Thank you very much for that :) Hope this thread helps someone else get to the solution quicker.

Comment: If Chrome displays correctly then you should open a thread on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php will need to be fixed in CEF.